# Python 3.6 Runtime overflow encountered

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

This error happens, when I try to run this line in a loop:

`sum((X@theta - y)**2)/2/len(X)`

After the 5th loop, i start to get the error.

> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
>
> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
>
> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in add

What to do, should I round the array or something? How?

If i try `round(sum((X@theta - y)**2)/2/len(X),5)`, i get this error

> TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __ round__ method

Comment: Overflow means your numbers are getting too large to be stored. You should either use a different number type to store your values, or rethink your algorithm. Rounding is not going to help.

Comment: A single number is getting large? Like 0.2345324324342423424234424324242342342342 ?

Comment: or total numbers in the matrix is getting large @9769953? I am new to python

Comment: A single number is too large (of a few numbers are; that doesn't matter); not the matrix size. Side note: your example number is not large in the sense of overflow, just in the sense or precision. A too large number would be 10^310, which is larger than [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can store. As another aside: this is not specific to Python, but goes for nearly every programming language.